# What is the name of this flower (saw this in Spain) which smells amazing?

Tags: identification, flowers

I saw this flower a week ago in Granada, Spain. It smells amazing, but I couldn't figure out the name of the plant. Does anyone have a clue?

[image: Flower]

[image: Flower close-up (lower right part)]

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately I can't see any leaves for 100% confirmation, but by the look of the flowers, the scent, and the shape of the pink buds held almost horizontally, I'd say it was Jasmine polyanthum. It's often sold as a houseplant in colder countries, does tolerate some cold, but not heavy frosting or freezing - nothing below 1 deg C, prefers temperature to remain above 5 deg C.

Answer (score 1):

[image][image]After much research on plants of Granada I found a very interesting link.

The name seems to be Trachelospermum Jasminoides - Rhynchospermum jasminoides or Star Jasmine.

It appears to be a medium sized evergreen shrub that produces clusters of sweet smelling flowers stating late spring.

it thrives in full sun and is drought resistant once established.